# Http, Https and Null reference exception C#

Tags: c#, http, https, nullreferenceexception

From my wix website i am trying to redirect to an external link website by clicking on a button. Let's say it's something like this

```
<a href="https://myurl.com" target="_blank" data-content="https://myurl.com" data-type="external" role="button" id="comp-irtj0t8jlink" class="style-j4gy21cvlink"><span id="comp-irtj0t8jlabel" class="style-j4gy21cvlabel" style="">
```

When i click the `button`, myurl.com gives a NullReferenceException and on the other side, if i get rid of that `s` at http, i am able to access `myurl.com`.
Which means it works and i don't get NullReferenceException.

```
<a href="http://myurl.com" target="_blank" ... >
```

On the other side, if i try to open `https://myurl.com` directly froom google, it works, as well as going to `http://myurl.com`

Any idea on what could be going wrong? Spent one day googling and nothing was relevant.

**EDIT:** When clicking the button described above, i get err_too_many_redirects from google and after this `myurl.com` gives me NullReferenceException.

Comment: is your site on https?

Comment: yes, as i have already written above, i am able to access `https://myurl.com` directly from google

Comment: I mean your wix website... is that on https or http?

Comment: If the code on that server is throwing an exception, you should really start by examining the exception instead just the link to the server.  At the very least the stack trace will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with http://myurl.com. Sounds like you should report the issue to them. They aren't handling referrers properly somehow.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan it is on https..

Comment: @David well i have the same scenario and server code working fine for other websites. That's why i am confused whether it's the website's problem, or on the server code.